# Weird behavior with globals and spl_autoload_register

Tags: php

Create the following files in the same folder. When you run both `a.php` and `b.php`, you'd expect both of them to print `Hello World`. What actually happens is that `a.php` prints `Hello World` but `b.php` prints nothing. Does anyone know what's going on?

a.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/globals.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/autoload.php');
Foo::bar();
```

b.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/autoload.php');
Foo::bar();
```

Foo.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/globals.php');
class Foo {
    public static function bar() {
        global $GLOB;
        echo $GLOB;
    }
}
```

globals.php

```
<?php
$GLOB = 'Hello World';
```

autoload.php

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require __DIR__ . '/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that `a.php` includes `global.php` in the global scope, so the keyword `global` in the `bar()` method can see it. The global scope is "alive" at that point.

However, on `b.php`, `global.php` is included inside the autoload function, in a scope that dies as soon as the autoload function finishes, and any variable declared there dies too. The definition of the `Foo` class doesn't follow this rule: once a class is defined, it does for any scope, (as long as the namespace is not changed) so the class definition won't die like the `$GLOB` variable.

Remember that `include` and `require` just expands the code inside the file in that place, so in `b.php`, it's like defining `$GLOB` there, inside `spl_autoload_register`.

Comment: Thanks! What are ways to get around this situation?

Comment: If you are using classes, a good practice would be to create static properties on your classes to hold variables. This is much better than global variables. You can easily access static variables with `Foo::myVar`, once you add them to your class, with `class Foo { static public myVar = 10; public static function bar() { ... } }`

Comment: So right now the globals file is used for storing config values for connections to the db and whatnot. So the way `Foo` is actually used is as a class to create a connection to the db so storing it as a static variable isn't the ideal situation right now. I think what I'll do now is either explicitly declare them to be global or to make sure the file is `required_once`'d before anything else. Not ideal, but I think that's the best quick-fix.

Comment: Another option is `define('name', 'value')`. It's used to define constants: they cannot be changed or redefined, and I think they are better for the needs you pointed out. They are used by many developers to store connection data.

Comment: As a comment to your static suggestion, @Marcovecchio, you should note that by calling Foo::myVar, you are actually calling for a class constant, which should be in uppercase like all other constants. To set a static variable inside a class you use <visibility> static $myVar, ex: `public static $myVar = 10;`. This can know be called by `Foo::$myVar`. You should also have uppercase letters in your define example as well

Comment: @wesleys : if you really want to go the global route, I believe the cleanest solution is to add `global $GLOB;` right _before_ either its definition in `globals.php` or the import in `Foo.php`

Answer (score 1):

When the autoloader loads the Foo class in `b.php`, it also loads globals. But what you didn't expect was that it loaded inside a closure and therefore not added to the global scope.

`$GLOB` is loaded in the global scope in `a.php`, but when not loaded before the autoloader, it only loads inside closure and therefor not available globally (unless you define that `$GLOB` should be global from inside the autoloader closure.

*Felt like the sentences became a little long and hard to understand, but hope you understood it*